# C# selenium Add cookies from json file

Tags: c#, selenium, cookies

I got json file contain cookies that I copy from chrome extension (editthiscookies chrome extension), format something like this

```
[
{
    "domain": ".sample.com",
    "expirationDate": 1702792429.54642,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_abck",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "unspecified",
    "secure": true,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "4u4y46htdhdg",
    "id": 1
},
{
    "domain": ".sample.com",
    "expirationDate": 1671263624.503405,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "ak_bmsc",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "unspecified",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "446363565365fdghdghj",
    "id": 2
},
```

is this cookies type can be use in C# and selenium, something like, store this cookies in txt file and load using C# to use in selenium to avoid input login and password every time visiting target site?

been read this thread [Creating cookies from Json file - does the type of the value matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560933/creating-cookies-from-json-file-does-the-type-of-the-value-matter) but still not understand how to use it (newbie here) meanwhile in selenium documentation, to add cookies, the format is something like

```
driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie("key", "value"));
```

should I explode each of them each? or put it as .toString(), but what the key what the value?? Sorry for newbie question

Thank you..

Comment: Does this help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74710047/5276946

Comment: thank you for the respond @ggeorge been try but unsuccessful, what Iam doing is 
login to tiktok via chrome, 
get json cookies using chrome extension called editthiscookie, 
save that in d:\cookie.txt, 
using that json file to login tiktok using C# and selenium, 
since u using console sample, I try to change the code to work in click button, I know I got wrong when changing the code but I really confuse here, can you check for me? 
this is the code i use based on your code https://pastebin.com/hvVEW41j

Comment: What is the problem? i can add cookies with this code in tiktok

Comment: Oops seem @ggeorge code is correct, its not work because the capitalize word, my bad :)

Comment: yes with dynamic we don't have intellisense :(.
If that code helped you give an upvote :)

Comment: I want to up vote but it said "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." but still I really thankfully for your code :)